# React-Native Grid Style

Tags: react-native

With the following code:

```
    <View style={{width:100,height:100,flexDirection:'row'}}>
        <View style={{width:50, height:100}}>
            a
        </View>
        <View style={{width:50, height:50}}>
            b
        </View>
        <View style={{width:50, height:50}}>
            c
        </View>
     </View>
```

--> [I want to (IMAGE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuXgU.png)

[image]

It is possible to do this with the "react-native-easy-grid" library.

However, it is possible to do this without using this library and with the above code structure. Without using rows and columns.

Can automatic placement be achieved by specifying only height and width values?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with flexbox:

```js
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection:'row'}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
    <Text>a</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection:'column'}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
      <Text>b</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
      <Text>c</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: That's not what I want to tell you. Is it possible to do this with my code? Only by specifying the width and height value, without creating rows and columns.

Comment: well, you can position the 'a' block absolutely and add 50 left padding to the wrapper (updated wrapper width will be 50 as well). `flexDirection: 'row'` will do the trick positioning 'b' and 'c'. But that feels really hacky, flex is meant to solve problems like this

Comment: Obviously I do not want to use "absolute". The project may impede further. I think there is no solution other than that :). Thank you dhorelik